# prove that $i_{*} :\ \Pi_{1}(A, a) \rightarrow \Pi_{1}(X, a)$ induced a isomorphism while X has a deformation retraction to A.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, retraction

$X$ is a topological space which has a deformation retraction to $A\subset X$, $a$ is an arbitrary element in $A$ and $i$ is an inclusion function.

A subspace $A$ of $X$ is called a ***deformation retract*** of $X$ if there is a homotopy $F:X\times I\rightarrow X$ (called a retract) such that for all $x\in X$ and $a\in A$,

$1.\; F(x,0)=x$,

$2.\; F(x,1) \in A$, and

$3.\; F(a,1)=a$.

We knew $i_{*}$ is one to one. because from (1) we have

$F\circ i$= $1_{A}$

and then

$(F\circ i)_{*}= F_{*}\circ i_{*}= 1_{\Pi_{1}(A,a)} $

Thus $i_{*}$ is injective.

***help me to show $i_{*}$ is surjective.***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $F\circ i$ doesn't make sense. Do you know that homotopies between maps induce natural transformations between the induced maps ?

Comment: I said Foi because we combined each side of equation  (1) $F(x,0)=1_{X}$ to i and then came to that conclusion $i_{*}$ is injective, I couldn't follow what you've said  how do you use that natural transformation  here? @MaximeRamzi

Comment: Well the point is that $g:= F_{\mid X\times \{1\}} : X\to A$ satisfies $g\circ i = id_A$ and $i\circ g \sim id_X$, the second one becomes a natural transformation $i_* \circ g_* \to id_{\Pi_1(X)}$

Comment: Aha right thank you, but  natural transformation between which maps you mean?  @MaximeRamzi

Comment: Thus I guess  we could say  $i_{*} o g_{*} \rightarrow id_{\Pi_{1}(A)}$ and so $i_{*}$ is surjective? am I right? @MaximeRamzi

Comment: What you define as a *deformation retract* is usually said to be a "strong deformation retract".

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Why not an official answer?